# OrderBy a List<Tuple<int, int>> by Item2 only

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> MyList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
```

The value of the list is as below:

```
int   int
0     2
0     1
0     4
1     2
1     3
1     0
2     0
2     9
2     1
3     2
3     5
3     2
```

How can I sort the `list` by *highest* value of `Item2` but save order of `Item1`? Like below:

```
int   int
2     0
2     9*
2     1
3     2
3     5*
3     2
0     2
0     1
0     4*
1     2
1     3*
1     0
```

Tried to use `MyList.OrderBy(x => x.Item2)` but no success

Comment: What's the desired sort order? The example *doesn't* sort by Item2. Unless you mean `find the max Item2 value per Item1 then order the tuples by the `Max` value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see, you want to order *groups* (not single items):

*group* with `Item1 == 2` comes first since this *group* has maximum `Item2` value  (`9`) over all other groups; *group* with `Item1 == 1` is the last, its maximum `Item2` value (`3`) is the smallest among other groups

```
2     0
2     9*
2     1
...
1     2
1     3*
1     0
```

To order *groups* let's try `GroupBy`:

```
var result = MyList
  .GroupBy(item => item.Item1)                               // groups
  .OrderByDescending(group => group.Max(item => item.Item2)) // are ordered
  .SelectMany(group => group);                               // then expanded
```

Comment: Works perfect. That's what I need. Thanks for your answer and explanations!